# Setting up HP Designjet 450C on network

Tags: networking, network-printer

I am looking for a way to setup a HP DesignJet 450C Plotter on a network so I can print from Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 os'.

My biggest issue is I do not see it appearing as listed in my router configuration, I'm just curious how I would being approaching this.

I have a good understanding of Networking and setting up printers but I have never attempted to setup significantly older technology to work with a modern network so I'm at a loss.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We need to know how you have the printer/plotter connected. Is it connected to a PC or directly to the network? Also, what researched have you done in an attempt to resolve this. What does HP's support site say about it? It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: The plotter is directly connected to the network. I haven't done much research, and I couldn't find it on the HP support site. This device is approximately 12 years old.

I've been more focused on the other printer I'm trying to setup, I just thought I'd ask this question as well since it will most likely need to be asked when I go more in-depth with trying to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, you can;

> **To upgrade your printer with a network interface**
>  You can connect your printer directly to a LAN using an HP JetDirect EX print server,
>   connected to the printer's parallel port. See page 1–18 and page
>   10–18.

It also states;

> For installation of the HP JetDirect EX interface with the DesignJet
>   430, 450C or 455CA, see the Installation Guide that comes with that
>   product.

Since you stated it is connected directly to the network, I will assume you already have the HP Jetdirect EX Plus Print Server J2591A called for on page 10-18 of the manual. Here is a link to the [JetDirect manual](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=27321&docId=emr_na-bpj06151&docLocale=en_US).

The problem you will have is finding drivers what will work with Windows 7 or 8. The [HP site](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=58816&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=54) only offers drivers for Windows 2000 thru XP.

Comment: The guy before me has apparently successfully sent a job to the plotter when directly connected but not through the network. I have not looked much into it and all I was told was to set up two computers so they could print to 2 Brother Printers, 1 Konica 7020, and the HP DesignJet 450C. 

Brother printers took a matter of minutes, the Konica appears to have a PostScript issues that I'm trying to resolve, and the DesignJet just does not provide any information. I am reading throug hthe manual to get a better understanding.